# Data persists in mutli page layout in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Is there a way of refreshing the a pariticular **div** with **data-role="page"** in **multi page layout**.I have gone through this link [Does jQuery's .data() cache persist across page transitions in jQuery mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085429/does-jquerys-data-cache-persist-across-page-transitions-in-jquery-mobile) but there is no solution for refreshing the div.I'm not loading any html content from any server.When I use **reload:true**,the whole application reloads(Is it because,Im using changeHash:false while navigating between pages).Thanks in advance.

```
$("#buttonID").click(function(){     
    $.mobile.changePage("#PageId",{
        allowSamePageTransition: true,
        transition: 'fade', 
        changeHash: false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
 <div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header" class="">
        <h3>Home</h3> 
    </div>
    <div role="main" id="mycontent" class="ui-content">
        "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...""There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."
        <a href="" data-role="none" class="ui-btn" id="btn-refresh"> Refresh    </a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn-refresh", function () {
    $("#mycontent").empty();
    $("#mycontent").html("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.");
    $("div[data-role=page]").trigger("create");
    $.mobile.changePage("#product_page", {
       allowSamePageTransition: true,
       transition: 'flip',
       changeHash: false
    });
})
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/94PGy/447/)**

Comment: I have a form that takes in an image, few text fields and a checkbox that needs to be sent to server.And Whenever i navigate to the form the 2nd time the data(the previously selected image and textfield's values)still remains.

Comment: Yes you can do simple ajax call. After get success call back from server you can change page.